# Include two different tables in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

Firstly I'm sorry. This is probably a rather basic question but I'm very new to this and couldn't find the answer on Google. I've the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM profile WHERE status = 'completed' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6
```

The member accounts in my database have two tables. Profile & Members. Profile includes details such as their job title, company, etc. and then Members stores their MD5 password, full name and cookie token. Now, both have a status column. The profile one has three options: not, needphoto and completed. The members status column has another three: inactive, active and terminated. I need a command that will select

```
from profile where status = 'completed' and members where status = 'active'
```

How can I achieve that? So the query will select six random members who've got active and completed profiles? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you will need to make a column in both the tables sharing same values for common entry. `Foreign Key` and `Primary Key`.

say both the tables has one `id` column.

So here is your SQL:

```
  select * from profile as p and member as m where p.id=m.id and p.status='completed' and m.status='active'
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the names of the columns are that links the two tables I can't give an exact query but this should show you what the basic concept is.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    profile,
    members
WHERE 
    profile.membersid = members.id
AND profile.status = 'completed' 
AND members.status = 'active'
ORDER BY 
    RAND() 
LIMIT 6
```

Answer (score 0):

you should look at Joins.

Try something like:

```
SELECT * FROM profile p
 LEFT JOIN members m ON m.profile_id = p.id
WHERE p.status = "completed" and m.status = 'active'
```

You may need to change the LEFT JOIN line, it depends what the link is between the 2 tables. It might just be `m.id = p.id`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.* FROM `profile` AS p, `members` AS m WHERE p.`ID` = m.`ID` AND p.`status` = "completed" AND m.`status` = "active"
```

You can use two tables in one query like above. You will probably need to add the column `ID` to join them together. It's advised to make these primary.

Please note the `p.*` is necessary otherwise SQL will give an error that two fields exists with the same name in the tables (`status` and `ID`)

Also try to use backticks for tables and columns, especially when using names that might be used by MySQL; e.g. `status` and `ID`.